# Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID - Login button does nothing when clicked

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

After the maintenance yesterday, I found myself logged out of Stack Overflow, though I was still logged in on other sites. I tried to log in again but was unable to do so - when I put the correct details in, and clicked 'Log in', nothing happened.

I've tried this on multiple sites (Stack and Scifi); and using Firefox, Edge, Chrome, as well as on a laptop and a mobile, so I'm fairly sure it's not just the PC playing up....

I've tried deleting all cookies; hard refresh on the page; and rebooting the PC, with no change. I'm somewhat rusty, but as to the console - I just used Ctrl-Shift-K to open the console the Firefox; it opened the Developer Tools, and the Console tab stays empty after I click.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? What happens after a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)? Try deleting all cookies and logging in again.

Comment: @Oded - question updated. Apologies - I should have added my attempts to the question initially.

Comment: What happens if you click "more login options", then "Log in"?

Comment: @Oded - then it works! That would have saved me having to remember my Google+ login details...

Comment: Yep, can reproduce with Chrome, and @Oded workaround also works.

Comment: @Oded looks like the initial Login button is of type "button" without any click handler attached to it. When clicking "more login options", it's being hidden then new Login button appears, this time of type "submit", hence working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yes, this is exactly what I am looking at. There were some markup and JS changes recently, and things are screwy right now.

Comment: Repro on Firefox too. Looks like @Shadow nailed it -- the button has no click handler to make it *do* anything.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, looks like changing it to submit will work, but of course I can't see the whole picture. Good luck fixing this! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the issue and am pushing out a fix as we speak.

With you in the next few minutes.

I'd appreciate being notified of any weirdness regarding login/signup.

Comment: Thank you. It's always good to get confirmation that I'm not imagining things.

Comment: Certainly, it's not you, it's us ;)